# idiomatic way to delete member message from protobuf message with arenas enabled

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I want to conditionally erase a member message a protocol-buffers message. The message may or may not have been created in an arena.

Does anyone know the correct idiomatic way to do this efficiently?

Here is what I have:

```
void erase_nested(testing::Exception& emsg)
{
    if(emsg.GetArena()) {
        // discard pointer
        emsg.unsafe_arena_release_nested();
    }
    else {
        delete emsg.release_nested();
    }
}
```

I could not find anything explicit in the docs about this.

For reference, the proto file:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package testing;

option cc_generic_services = true;
option cc_enable_arenas = true;

/// Carry a nested exception across a comms link
message Exception
{
    string name = 1;
    string what = 2;
    Exception nested = 3;
}
```

Comment: How about `emsg.clear_nested();`?

Comment: @KerrekSB gah! how did I miss that?? tyvm.